# Custom Entity in SketchUp that follows in export

Tags: ruby, export, sketchup

I'm writing a plugin for SketchUp in where I need to create a visible and movable 3d entity that also gets included in a Collada format export (and specifically the `model.export` function).

I've seen no mentions in the documentations if it's possible to add custom entities, but I've also learned that the documentation isn't always complete.

What I've set out to do could also be achieved by adding custom attributes to a specific entity, but I've found no indication that custom attributes get exported either.

Anyone got any useful information on how to bend `model.export` to your will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All API methods is documented - there are none missing. What you might have heard is that the explanation is some times not the best - but it is complete.

There is no way to create custom entities.

You can add attributes via `Sketchup::Entity.set_attribute` (http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/entity#set_attribute), but what gets exported is entirely dependent on the exporter. I don't believe the Collada exporter will write API defined attributes to the exported model.

Not exactly sure what custom entity or attributes you had in mind - nor how it would appear in the COLLADA file, but you might need to write your own exporter tailored to your need.

Comment: Ok, thanks! For the moment I've solved it by programmatically creating a "standard" 3d entity with a generated name that gets included in the file export.